# Find out null from a Struct data type in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark

I have a employee table where address is of struct data type and some of the values inside struct are null.So how to find out the rows where we dont have a single null with spark sql.I got the answer for a small table where we have two field in the struct with below..but how to find out if we have more than 100 fields in the struct type ..do we want to create udf or any other approch?

```
df.filter($"address.city".isNotNull and $"address.pin".isNotNull).show()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Get column names:

```scala
val fields = df.select($"address.*").columns
```

and use filter:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.where(fields map(c => col(s"address.`$c`").isNotNull) reduce(_ and _))
```

To skip empty strings just add:

```scala
df.where(fields map(c => col(s"address.`$c`")) 
                map(c => not(trim(c) <=> "") and  c.isNotNull)
                reduce(_ and _))
```